# Java MongoDB Morphia: find a object by ObjectId id

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-ee, morphia

I am using Morphia and a DAO Class. I have a Class with an Id ObjectId:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class GeoProfileVo extends ResponseVo implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4975628041316056892L;

    @Id private ObjectId id;

    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String city;

    //Getters, Setters and toString
}
```

GeoProfileDAO:

```
public class GeoProfileDAO extends BasicDAO<GeoProfileVo, ObjectId>{

    public GeoProfileDAO(Morphia morphia, MongoClient mongoClient, String db) {
        super(mongoClient, morphia, db);
    }

    public GeoProfileVo findByNme(String name){
        return getDs().find(GeoProfileVo.class, "name", name).get();
    }

    //Here is the problem
    public GeoProfileVo findById (ObjectId id){
        //return getDs().find(GeoProfileVo.class).field("id").equal(id).get();
        return getDs().get(GeoProfileVo.class, id);
    }

    public ObjectId saveGeoProfile(GeoProfileVo geoProfileVo){
        return (ObjectId) getDs().save(geoProfileVo).getId();
    }
}
```

My Service:

```
public class GeolocationService implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2071937170723089158L;

    /** The Constant log. */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(GeolocationService.class.getName());

    private MongoClient mongoClient;
    private GeoProfileDAO geoProfileDAO;

    public GeolocationService(){
        super();
        LOGGER.info("[GeolocationService - Constructor] - init");

        //mongoClient:
        mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);

        //morphia:
        Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
        morphia.map(GeoProfileVo.class);

        //morphia dao:
        geoProfileDAO = new GeoProfileDAO(morphia, mongoClient, "mydb");
    }

    public GeoProfileVo updateGeoProfile(GeoProfileVo geoProfileVo) throws GeoProfileNotFoundException{
        LOGGER.info("[GeolocationService - updateGeoProfile] - init");
        long currentSystemTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

        if(geoProfileVo == null){
            LOGGER.error("[GeolocationService - updateGeoProfile] - geoProfileVo cannot be null");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if(geoProfileVo.getId() == null){
            LOGGER.error("[GeolocationService - updateGeoProfile] - ID cannot be null");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        GeoProfileVo geoProfileVoEntity = geoProfileDAO.findById(geoProfileVo.getId());
        if(geoProfileVoEntity==null){
            LOGGER.error("[GeolocationService - updateGeoProfile] - geoProfileVo not found in BD");
            throw new GeoProfileNotFoundException();
        }

        LOGGER.debug("[GeolocationService - updateGeoProfile] - Finish Timing:"+(System.currentTimeMillis()-currentSystemTime));
        return geoProfileDAO.updateGeoProfile(geoProfileVo);
    }

    //CRUD

}
```

I am able to search by email, name or city, insert a object in BD but I am not able to search by id. In google I only find information about a String id and I don´t find much information about id type ObjectId. when I try to find by the ObjectId Id, doesn´t find nothing and returns null.

For example, when I find by email, returns:

```
{
       "id":    {
          "timestamp": 1432028968,
          "machineIdentifier": 9913253,
          "processIdentifier": 7516,
          "counter": 8215016
       },
       "email": "aaa@gmail.com",
       "name": "john",
       "city": "Madrid"
}
```

I call a WS that call a createGeoProfile Service with the same Object with the same id but in Eclipse IDE, the "id" is different in each call. Maybe the problem is here but I don´t understand it.

How do I find an object with id type ObjectId?

Comment: You can use `ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId("YOUR ID");` or stringId = "YOUR ID" and `return getDs().get(GeoProfileVo.class, stringId);`

Comment: Sorry but I don´t know where is the "YOUR ID" or find it.

I saw this post but it is 4 years ago and it is not mark as resolved.

Comment: It doesn't look like your objects are saving properly.  There should be no field called "geoProfileVo" in a Morphia saved document.  And the ObjectId is not saving properly, either.  It should be an ObjectId in the bson in the shell.  Something is definitely wrong here but it's not looking like Morphia is at the center of it.

Comment: Also, you have duplicate keys in your json.  I'd be very surprised if that came via Morphia.  There's something else at play here.

Comment: @evanchooly I edit the response of when I find by email because I had copied my request object. The response doesn´t have the field "geoProfileVo". Sorry.

Comment: @evanchooly where do you see the duplicate keys? It is the first time that I use Morphia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He solution was return a ObjectId.toString() when I insert a object in BD. I understand that this objectId is similar to a Hash, so when I want to find by Id, I cannot sent an ObjectId type because this ObjectId changes. For this reason, we must return a toString() (this part was that I didn´t undestand).

With this String, we instantiate an ObjectId that we use it for find by id:

```
public GeoProfileVo findById (String id){
    ObjectId oid = new ObjectId(id);
    return getDs().find(GeoProfileVo.class).field("id").equal(oid).get();
}

public String saveGeoProfile(GeoProfileVo geoProfileVo){
    return getDs().save(geoProfileVo).getId().toString();
}
```

In the end, to avoid having an ObjectId type that I will not use it, I change the Id in my GeoProfileVo to type String.

```
@Id private String id;
```

Now, the response of FindById, contains the id in String type:

```
{
   "id": "555c44e39743a5141c00d0a1",
   "email": "aaa@gmail.com",
   "name": "john",
   "city": "Madrid"
}
```

Comment: Um.  you can use ObjectId directly and query by it.  we have tests in morphia and in production doing just that.